# Кусты и кущи

Tags: этимология, грамотная-речь

В речи часто заросли называют кущами, особенно часто - в переносном значении, например, "райские кущи". По крайней мере, я часто это слышу и читаю в текстах. Но ведь кущи - это, насколько я знаю, ритуальные постройки иудеев, в которые они временно переходили жить на один из праздников, и к растительности отношения они не имеют.
Правильно ли вообще употреблять слово "кущи" в значении "кусты", "заросли", то есть, вошло ли это в язык официально, или это все-таки неграмотно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово КУЩА первоначально имело значение "шатер, шалаш, хижина". Заимств. из цслав.; ср. ст.-слав. кѦшта, болг. къща "дом", сербохорв. кÿħа "дом, кухня", словен. кóčа. Действительно, слово КУЩА связано с кучками - "еврейским праздником кущей". Но в современном русском языке у слова КУЩА два значения: 1. Шатёр, хижина, жилище. 2. Листва, крона дерева (деревьев), заросли, чаща. Слово употребляется обычно в поэтической речи. Словосочетание *райские кущи* имеет ироническую окраску. Так говорят о каком-л. месте как о воплощении обилия и благополучия. Оба значения зафиксированы в словаре.

Переход от 'шалаша' к 'кустам', вероятно (мое личное предположение), произошел из-за аналогии с регулярным чередованием согласных *шт/щ/ст*, например: ра**ст**и - выра**щ**ивать.